# Failed to register package for vnd.sun.star.expand:$UNO_USER_PACKAGES_CACHE/uno_packages/lu15798vfxfyn.tmp_/apso(3).oxt/python/scripts

Tags: python, ubuntu-18.04, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

Version: 6.0.7.3
Build ID: 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.10
CPU threads: 4; OS: Linux 5.3; UI render: default; VCL: gtk3; 
Locale: en-IN (en_IN); Calc: group

i am getting `Failed to register package for vnd.sun.star.expand:$UNO_USER_PACKAGES_CACHE/uno_packages/lu15798vfxfyn.tmp_/apso(3).oxt/python/scripts` error

download link is https://gitlab.com/jmzambon/apso/raw/v1.2.5/apso.oxt 
please help me

Answer (score 1):

Try to rename the file you downloaded "apso(3).oxt" to its correct name "apso.oxt".

That "(3)" was added by your browser when you downloaded the file for the fourth time, but somehow it made LO mad. I had the same problem and I solved it this way, maybe you're lucky too.

Comment: That worked for me on Ubuntu20, even for the `codehighlighter.oxt` extension, which had after downloading the original filename `de554345-codehighlighter.oxt` .

Answer (score 1):

The following solved it for me:

```
sudo apt install libreoffice-script-provider-python
```

NB May be also restarting LBO and user profile clean up are needed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs for me as well. APSO installs successfully on Windows, but not on Ubuntu. Other python-uno extensions install successfully on Ubuntu, so there may be some problem with APSO. Consider contacting the owner or filing an issue at https://gitlab.com/jmzambon/apso/-/issues.

Keep in mind that, while APSO is convenient, it is not necessary for python macro development. Navigate to `user/Scripts/python` and create a .py file as explained at [Transfer from Basic to Python](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python/Transfer_from_Basic_to_Python), or open a python prompt and enter `import uno`.

Comment: thanks for your help but i have no idea how to do that

Comment: How to do what - file an issue or follow the documentation in the link? There's also a tutorial: http://christopher5106.github.io/office/2015/12/06/openoffice-libreoffice-automate-your-office-tasks-with-python-macros.html